# Swift 2: is there a short syntax to conditionally set a non-optional variable from an optional variable?

Tags: swift2, optional-variables

Sometimes I find myself writing swift 2 code like this:

```
class Test {
    var optionalInt: Int?
    var nonOptionalInt: Int = 0
    func test() {
        if let i = optionalInt {
            nonOptionalInt = i
        }
        // do more stuff
    }
}
```

where the problematic part is this:

```
if let i = optionalInt {
    nonOptionalInt = i
}
```

In words:
if optionalInt has a value, assign it to the variable nonOptionalInt, else do nothing.

Is there an equivalent way in swift 2 to express this in a elegant single line without adding an intermediate variable with if let i?

**Edit**

after contemplating the first answers...

Obviously there is an equivalent way

```
if optionalInt != nil {
    nonOptionalInt = optionalInt!
}
```

Ternary operators ? : are not equivalent as they may trigger a didSet which the original code does not (good if this is a intended side effect)

The most elegant answer so far appears to be

```
nonOptionalInt = optionalInt ?? nonOptionalInt
```

it may also trigger a didSet like the ternary operator and therefore is not equivalent (also good if this is intended).

I think my wish to Apple would be something like

```
nonOptionalInt = optionalInt ??
```

or

```
nonOptionalInt ??= optionalInt
```

Comment: Unfortunately there is no swifter way which is semantically the same

Answer (score 10, accepted):

What you are looking for is the [nil coalescing operator](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/BasicOperators.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH6-ID72).

You would use it like so in this case:

```
nonOptionalInt = optionalInt ?? nonOptionalInt
```

**EDIT**

re: your last edit to your question:

"*I think my wish to Apple would be something like* `nonOptionalInt ??= optionalInt`"

...why wish when you can build it?  :)

I haven't thought about it enough to decide whether I would recommend something like this for the general case, but if it helps in your situation you can create a `??=` operator that does what you ask like this:

```
infix operator ??= {}

func ??= <T>(inout lhs: T, rhs: T?) -> Void {
  guard let value = rhs else { return }
  lhs = value
}
```

then, to see it in action:

```
let optionalNil: String? = nil,
  optionalValue: String? = "optionalValue",
  implicitlyUnwrappedNil: String! = nil,
  implicitlyUnwrappedValue: String! = "implicitlyUnwrappedValue"
var a = "a", b = "b", c = "c", d = "d"

a ??= optionalNil               // "a"
b ??= optionalValue             // "optionalValue"
c ??= implicitlyUnwrappedNil    // "c"
d ??= implicitlyUnwrappedValue  // "implicitlyUnwrappedValue"
```

*(note that you would add this definition at top-level scope, outside of the definition of any class, struct, or other type)*

Comment: Looks a little more elegant to me than the code example in my question. It has a different semantics as it may trigger a didSet in the nil case that the original code doesn't.

Answer (score 6):

Swift 4.0 Version build from the 2.0er answer

```
/// Optional Assignment, assigns if value exists
infix operator ?=: AssignmentPrecedence

func ?=<T>(lhs: inout T, rhs: T?)  {

    guard let value = rhs else { return }
    lhs = value
}

// Playground Test

var dummy = "old"
var opt :String?

dummy ?= opt // leaves old

opt = "new"
dummy ?= opt // value becomes new
```

Answer (score 2):

> Is there an equivalent way in swift 2 to express this in a elegant
>   single line without adding an intermediate variable with if let i?

You can omit the intermediate value if you want to:

```
if optionalInt != nil {
    nonOptionalInt = optionalInt!
}
```

And you can obviously put that all on a single line if you want:

```
if optionalInt != nil { nonOptionalInt = optionalInt! }
```

But you can also use the ternary operator if you prefer:

```
nonOptionalInt = (optionalInt != nil) ? optionalInt! : 0
```

where the `0` is just a default value to use in the case where `optionalInt == nil`. If you don't want to change `nonOptionalInt` if `optionalInt == nil` then just use `nonOptionalInt`:

```
nonOptionalInt = (optionalInt != nil) ? optionalInt! : nonOptionalInt
```

Note that the `!` in `optionalInt!` implicitly unwraps the optional value -- it's the way you tell the compiler that you know that `optionalInt` isn't `nil` so it's okay to assign to a non-optional variable.

Comment: Thanks for your effort. Yes, obviously one can write if statements in one line. Doesn't make it less complex. Using a ternary operator has a different semantics as it triggers a didSet which the original code does not.